# Deploy an app on my own server without the port number in the address

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have set up my own server with R and shiny-server, and had already put some apps on that.

However, all apps have a port number like the `:3838` in `blahblah.com:3838/app_name`, which doesn't look very nice, if my future plan is to build an entire site using shiny.

So if that is possible to change some configuration that I can remove the `:3838` from the address?

Comment: You could use an http redirect from the :80 server.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change a setting in the Shiny Server config file (change the port it listens on). See below (assuming you are running Ubuntu):

Find the shiny server config file (available in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf). Find the line:

```
# Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 3838;
```

Change that to 80 (which is the default http port).

Then restart the shiny server service:

```
service shiny-server restart
```

All your apps will now be running through the :80 (or regular http port), which you don't need to mention when typing out the link.

NOTE: I'm not sure how this might affect other websites you might be hosting (I only run shiny/rstudio server on my box, so that wasn't something I needed to worry about).

For more information, see the [shiny server documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/) (Section 2.1 for your specific question)