# R shiny web : Application not accessible from international institutions (proxy closed)

Tags: shiny

I've developped a web shiny application. 
This application is already accesible from internet ( from my house for example). But this application has to be accessible from international institutions (ambassy..). Due to their security protocol, they can not access to my application.. I think it is due to closed proxy. The link internet application is like this xxxx.xxx.xxx:8383
It's not possible to modify their internet security protocol.
Do you have any idea ? how i can make this web application accessible from (almost)anywhere.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify the shiny-server.conf file to set the server to listen on port 80 (HTML) instead of 3838. See my answer here: [Deploy an app on my own server without the port number in the address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973026/deploy-an-app-on-my-own-server-without-the-port-number-in-the-address/30080934#30080934)