# R Shiny - use page instead of port

Tags: r, web, shiny, port

I've followed the directions [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson1/) and [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/runApp.html) to get a `Shiny` hello world app running on my webserver but I can only access it via my homepage then a port number. For example, `R` shows `Listening on http://0.0.0.0:6548` and I need to type in `myHostName.org:6548` and I can see my app.

If I want to turn this into `myHostName.org/app1` instead, how can I do this?

Comment: are you using the shiny server or just running it via Rscript or an R console session?

Comment: I'm running `R` interactively and using `runApp`.

Comment: there's a `port` parameter for `runApp()` then, but if you want to hang it off a `/path` then that's either moving to using shiny server or configuring your web server software to deal with the proxy/forwarding.

Comment: If you have Apache or Nginx installed on your server, this can be done easily using a reverse proxy.

Comment: Answer is here. Feel free to vote for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973026/deploy-an-app-on-my-own-server-without-the-port-number-in-the-address/30080934#30080934